# Shell script to work on files in some directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command, arguments

I have a Windows system, so I downloaded cygwin to help me execute Linux/unix commands. I need to execute a shell script on a bunch of apks stored inside a folder (got the script [here](http://www.modaco.com/topic/329285-signing-roms-with-the-aosp-platform-cert-for-flibblesan/?p=2221979)).

This is the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd $1

for filename in *.apk
do
    unzip -d $filename.extract $filename META-INF/CERT.RSA
    if [ -f $filename.extract/META-INF/CERT.RSA ]
        then
        mkdir `keytool -printcert -v -file $filename.extract/META-INF/CERT.RSA|grep SerialNumber| cut -c 19-23`
        mv $filename `keytool -printcert -v -file $filename.extract/META-INF/CERT.RSA|grep SerialNumber| cut -c 19-23`/$filename
        mv `echo $filename | sed 's/\(.*\.\)apk/\1odex/'` `keytool -printcert -v -file $filename.extract/META-INF/CERT.RSA|grep SerialNumber| cut -c 19-23`/`echo $filename | sed 's/\(.*\.\)apk/\1odex/'`
        rm -rf $filename.extract
    else
        mkdir none
        mv $filename none
        mv `echo $filename | sed 's/\(.*\.\)apk/\1odex/'` none
        rm -rf $filename.extract
    fi
done;

mkdir other
mv * other
mv other/b399 platform
mv other/f2a7 shared
mv other/f2b9 media
mv other/936e test
```

In the terminal I execute the command `sh cert.sh`,but I get the below error:

[image]

Strangely,when I execute `cert.sh -` the script runs and separates my apks into different folders,but I am not sure if it runs correctly as the proper command to run a shell script is `sh cert.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script expects an argument when it's executed. This argument is the directory where `*.apk` resides.

The argument is called in the script by `cd $1` line, this is how arguments are called in shell scripting.

Please try to rerun your script in the following manner: `sh cert.sh </path/where/apks/reside>` and see if that resolves your issue?

Also, before `for` loop add `rm -rf other` and `rm -rf none` lines to remove the errors relating to existing folders.

Comment: Things seem to work fine now.Just to confirm.I put all my apks inside one directory namely - 'C:\Users\Tharun Mathew\Desktop\test1' . I put my cert.sh also inside this directory.Then in my cmd prompt I run - 'sh cert.sh .' . This is fine, right?

Comment: @Basher51 That's correct. the `.` passes the desired location. So if your script is in the same location as the `apk`s you can run it as you suggested `sh cert.sh .`. Note that your script can be located anywhere in the file system as long as you pass the path to the `apk` directory properly. Lastly, if this has worked for you, pls mark as an answer :-).

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.Just wondering though,why when I executed 'cert.sh -' or 'cert.sh -help' I saw that the script executed and segregated my apks? Why did those command execute the script when the actual command is 'sh cert.sh <path>'  ?

Comment: @Basher51 no problem, glad I could help! Most of the errors come from pre existing libraries, namely `other` and `non`. This particular script does not have the logic to test the input argument (i.e. to check if it's a valid directory or just a string), and that's why it still ran with `-help` or `-` (or any string for that manner); the output was `no such directory...`  on top. As for segregation, I suspect it's b/c of the fact that the bottom six commands are outside of the `for` loop and thus always executed. Might be better to edit the script a little.....

Comment: I just intend to get the apks segregated in 'platform' folder for some other use.As long as I get all the genuine apks(as per the script logic) inside this folder,then its fine(which I hope it does).Should you see a bug then pls do let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

The script is executing fine. It would not produce all of those errors if it weren't.

You have the following issues:

1) There aren't any files with the suffix .apk in your ...\test1 directory and your script has not been written to handle this kind of error. Ditto for *.odex.

2_ The script expects to be able to create the directories `none` and `other`, but they already exist (and appear to be files rather than directories) and it doesn't have know how to handle that, so it outputs an error.

The rest of your errors are related to the above.

Suggestions:

1) If you have no *.apk files, then comment out that entire `if` statement. Otherwise move to the directory that does contain them.

2) Remove the files `none` and `other` if they aren't required. If they remain as files, then your script will never create those directories.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I had all my .apk files inside the directory(and it was not empty either).The issue I had,as Simply_Me pointed out,is that I needed to give the path of location of my apk files.